# Prove that $x \sin x$ and $x^3 + x + 1$ intersect

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working on some problems and this particular one caught me off guard. Just by reading it, I thought it was a very simple problem where I equate the two equations and solve for $x$. However, my attempt was futile and I am stuck.

> Prove that the graphs of the functions $y = x \sin x$ and $y = x^3 + x + 1$ intersect.
>
> Hint: Check the values at x = -1, and x = 0

Any hints or help are greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: To find points of intersection, equate the two equations and solve for $x$.

Comment: @Mhenni, I would like to see you solve $x\sin x=x^3+x+1$ for $x$.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = x \sin x - (x^3+x+1)$ and apply the hint.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I leave it to you you to work it out :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See if you can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.  If a continuous function changes sign on interval, it must be zero somewhere on the interval.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I got it now! Thank you all for your time :)